# What are my best options to get a list of coworkers in my user’s company?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, microsoft-teams, slack, auth0

I’m building an app that allows an employee to send an email to all or selected coworkers in in their company. I understand that I’ll need to let my user import a list of coworkers from one of the platforms their company uses. I could use some guidance as to which platforms allow such access to the list of coworkers (Slack? MS Teams? Google Workplace?), any considerations I should keep in mind, and whether there’s a single platform I can integrate with that will allow my users to choose between multiple platforms to import their coworkers from.

Comment: You can get user of your company by using api, could you please check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)  try if that helps. Also could you please explain the scenario in more detail.

Comment: Please let us know does that documentation helps for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge

You can get user of your company by using graph api, could you please check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) of list users.